# Convert day and time to UNIX time

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

I got 3 numeric text fields which are days, hours and min. I have scripted in such a way that user can only type 2 digit for each field.

Can someone help me to combine this 3 fields into one integer (which is a UNIX time) so that I can save it in the database as a single column time.

**HTML**

```
<table><tr>
<td><input id='days' type='text' maxLength='2' placeholder='Days'></td>
<td><input id='hours' type='text' maxLength='2' placeholder='hours'></td>
<td><input id='min' type='text' maxLength='2' placeholder='Min'></td>
</tr></table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var day = document.getElementById('days').value;
var hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
var min = document.getElementById('min').value;
```

How do I combine this 3 variable (day,hours,min) into one single unix time variable and save it in the database. ( I know how to save it in the database but ? How do I combine the 3 variable and save it in a single JavaScript variable ? )

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: How do days, hours & minutes make a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I'm using you want to use the current month and year? You need to post the fields to your PHP script and use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to formulate a timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-M') . '-' . $_POST['days'] . ' ' . $_POST['hours'] . ':' . $_POST['min']);
```

Or, using JavaScript:

```
var d = new Date();
var ts = Math.round((new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), $('#day').val(), $('#hours').val(), $('#min').val())).getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: Hi , I worked on this but it is still giving me a wrong integer

Answer (score 0):

[Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are the number of seconds since the beginning of the unix epoch.

[The javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has a getTime method that returns the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the unix epoch.

So, if you want the value calculated on the client side:

```
var time = new Date(0,0,day,hours,min);
var milliseconds = time.getTime();
var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
```

I'm not including an example of how to send a value to the server and save it to the database - that completely depends on the server-side technology you are using, and a quick google or stackoverflow search will help you with that part.